# Dash datatable save to excel or csv with popup window

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is it possible to save a dash datatable locally with the standard popup window? Where one can select location, file_name etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the standard export functionality?

Comment: I haven't been able to find the information on it, I find the dash documentation difficult to navigate. https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference here it mentions export_columns, export_headers and export_format, but I've not seen an example of how it is used. Do you have a link where this is shown?

Comment: If you add export_format="csv", I believe an export button should appear.

Comment: Okay that does work although it just downloads it, I don't get the option to set a file name or location, so I'll leave the question open.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if the desired behavior can be achieved with the default table export mechanism (enabled by setting `export_format` argument), but it can be done using the `Download` component from `dash-extensions==0.0.28`. Here is a small example of the latter,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
from dash_extensions import Download
from dash_table import DataTable
from dash_extensions.snippets import send_data_frame

dt = DataTable(columns=[{"id": v, "name": v} for v in range(5)], data=[{v: v * 10 for v in range(5)}], id="table")
app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([dt, html.Button("Download", id="btn"), Download(id="download")])


@app.callback(Output("download", "data"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")], [State("table", "data")])
def download_table(n_clicks, data):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
    return send_data_frame(df.to_csv, "some_data.csv", index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

EDIT: As per Dash 1.20.0 the `Download` component has been merged into `dash-core-components`. The above example can thus be rewritten without the use of any third-party libraries,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
from dash_table import DataTable

dt = DataTable(columns=[{"id": v, "name": v} for v in range(5)], data=[{v: v * 10 for v in range(5)}], id="table")
app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([dt, html.Button("Download", id="btn"), dcc.Download(id="download")])

@app.callback(Output("download", "data"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")], [State("table", "data")])
def download_table(n_clicks, data):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
    return dcc.send_data_frame(df.to_csv, "some_data.csv", index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: I just tried this but there is no pop up, it just downloads it to the downloads folder. But thanks

Comment: What OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I am too - and i am seeing the popup. Maybe you have disabled the popup in your browser settings? To check, go to "chrome://settings/downloads"  and check that "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is turned on.

Comment: This is a great tool. However this is not downloading my full datatable (a very large one) why is that?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but one solution that I found can be to use a `clientside_callback` and the `showSaveFilePicker` javascript function like such, where I download some data from a dcc.Store to a `json` file:

```
clientside_callback(
    """
    async function(data) {
        if (!data) {
            return dash_clientside.no_update;
        }
        try {
            const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker({
                suggestedName: 'data.json',
                types: [{
                    description: 'JSON file',
                    accept: {
                        'application/json': ['.json'],
                    },
                }],
            });
            const writableStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
            await writableStream.write(data);
            await writableStream.close();
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);
            return dash_clientside.no_update;
        }
    }
""",
    Output("dummy", "children"), # the callback doesn't return anything so a dummy output is used.
    Input("data_store", "data"), # data from the dcc.Store
)
```